# SKSpriteNode creates a thin coloured line

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

So I am using 3 `SKSpriteNode`'s in my application. `floorSprite`, `leftWall` and `rightWall`.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
    let floorSprite = SKSpriteNode()//(imageNamed: "floor")
    floorSprite.alpha = 0.0
    floorSprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: CGPoint.zero.y)
    floorSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: floorSprite.size.height + 12))
    floorSprite.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    floorSprite.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.4
    floorSprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.minX, y: self.frame.minY + (floorSprite.size.height / 2))
    floorSprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0x1 << 1
    floorSprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x1 << 1
    floorSprite.zPosition = 4
    floorSprite.aspectFillToSize(self.frame.size)
    self.addChild(floorSprite)
    self.floorSprite = floorSprite
    
    let leftwall = SKSpriteNode()
    leftwall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 0.1, height: self.frame.size.height*2))
    leftwall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x1 << 1
    leftwall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    leftwall.position = CGPoint(x: 0 , y: self.frame.size.height / 2.0)
    leftwall.zPosition = 4
    leftwall.physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0
    self.addChild(leftwall)
    
    let rightwall = SKSpriteNode()
    rightwall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 0.1, height: self.frame.size.height*2))
    rightwall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x1 << 1
    rightwall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    rightwall.physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0
    rightwall.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width , y: self.frame.size.height / 2.0)
    rightwall.zPosition = 4
    self.addChild(rightwall)
```

Here is a screenshot of the issue I have. You can see the light blue lines that shows. If I remove the `self.addChild` line, the Sprite is not there, and the light blue color gone.
[CLICK HERE FOR IMAGE.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0IvV.png)

Any ideas what might be wrong here? I have tried adding `leftWall.isHidden = true` and `leftWall.alpha = 0.0` but that has no effect...

Comment: do you have `.showsPhysics = true`  on the view attached to the scene?

Comment: @RezaShirazian You're a lifesaver. Removed that line and it's all fint now, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you have `SKScene.showPhysics` on.. turn this off in your appdelegate (or didmovetoview) or wherever you turned it on, and the lines should go away.

These are caused by your physics bodies :)